# Start and Stop Cloud SQL via Java mysql admin-api

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm not able to find a way to simply start and stop a Cloud SQL instance using java mysql admin-api.

I found this official google documentation that explain how to start and stop the Cloud SQL instance via gcloud: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/start-stop-restart-instance But I'm not able to obtain the same things via java using mysql admin-api,

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the [Cloud SQL Admin API for Java](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/api-lib/java) is used for operations such as the one you are looking for. If you are using Maven, you can add the library to your project adding the following lines of code to the `pom.xml` configuration file:

```
<project>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-sqladmin</artifactId>
      <version>v1beta4-rev48-1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

***EDIT:***

As far as I can see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/start-stop-restart-instance), the underlying API uses the `Instance.Patch` method for starting and stopping instances, although I cannot find any specific information about how to do it. However, you can find more relevant information yourself in the [Instances:Patch](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/patch) page. I will keep looking for more information and in case I find something relevant, I will post a comment to this answer below.

***EDIT 2:***

I have been performing some tests using the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/cloud%20sql/sqladmin/v1beta4/sql.instances.patch), using the `PROJECT_ID`, `SQL_INSTANCE_ID` and a JSON body such as this one:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "activationPolicy": "YOUR_PREFERED_STATE"
  }
}
```

According to the documentation:

> The activation policy specifies when the instance is activated; it is
>   applicable only when the instance state is RUNNABLE. Valid values: 
>   ALWAYS: The instance is on, and remains so even in the absence of
>   connection requests.  NEVER: The instance is off; it is not activated,
>   even if a connection request arrives.  ON_DEMAND: First Generation
>   instances only. The instance responds to incoming requests, and turns
>   itself off when not in use. Instances with PER_USE pricing turn off
>   after 15 minutes of inactivity. Instances with PER_PACKAGE pricing
>   turn off after 12 hours of inactivity.

I have tried running the API with the **NEVER** and **ALWAYS** states, and my Cloud SQL instance stopped and started accordingly. So in your case, and going back to the Admin API for Java, you should be looking at the *Settings* of your instance, specifically at [this method](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sqladmin/v1beta4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sqladmin/model/Settings.html#setActivationPolicy(java.lang.String)):

```
public Settings setActivationPolicy(java.lang.String activationPolicy)
```

Changing the *Activation Policy* to NEVER or ALWAYS should be what you need here, although you can have a look at the other possible instance states in case they fit your requirements better.

Comment: Pay attention! Do not use it! This is the method to delete the instance not the metodo to start and stop an instence- Please modify your answer!

Comment: Ooops! You are completely right, I misunderstood the question. I am editting it right now.

Comment: I think OP can find in my answer now what he needed. Sorry for my previous missunderstanding

Comment: No problem! I am happy to help. And sorry again for the confusion earlier.